# Display content inline inside to bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 table that shows monetary value information, but I have a display problem in the responsive mode, then I detail my problem:

I have the following Html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">#</th>
       <th scope="col">First</th>
       <th scope="col">Last</th>
       <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>$ 1,543,3345,432</td>
        <td>$ 1,456,334,4545</td>
        <td>$ 1,000,0202</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

On the PC it is displayed perfectly:
[image]

But in response mode the problem appears:
[image]

What I want is that in the responsive mode, it looks like the pc. I have tried several ways to change the css to get this, but I could not.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could remove the space between the dollar sign and number, or replace it with a non-breaking space &nbsp;

Comment: white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 2):

You can give width to table and make it inline and another way is applying to white-space: nowrap; of  `table tr td`

```css
.tablewd{
   min-width:450px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-hover tablewd">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">#</th>
       <th scope="col">First</th>
       <th scope="col">Last</th>
       <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>$ 1,543,3345,432</td>
        <td>$ 1,456,334,4545</td>
        <td>$ 1,000,0202</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap-4's **`text-nowrap`** class for the table to avoid text break.

```css
/* Source: Bootstrap-4 source code*/
.text-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLpzwe

Answer (score 0):

You should add more css:

```
.table td {  white-space: nowrap; }
```